# WSO2 APIManager: How can I set the OAuth Access Token expiration time

Tags: wso2-api-manager

We want to try to reduce the life time of our OAuthAccessTokens (generated by an WSO2 API Manager JWT Grant). We tried to do it in the application by setting the 'Validity Period', by changing the AccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod in the identity.xml file, by changing the time settings in the service provider but nothing changed the validity period of the token. It stays always at 3600 seconds.
Can anyone give us a hint and with which attributes to change the expiration time of the OAuthAccessTokens?

Regards
Edmund

Comment: What is the api manager version that you use?

Comment: I am using WSO2 APIManager 2.6.0 and 3.0.0

Comment: To clarify your issue does the token response has the validity period as 3600 and/ or in the api store UI you always see the validity period as 3600?

Comment: Hi,
when receiving the new OAuth2Token from the WSO2 /oauth2/token API, the token has an expiration time of 3600 seconds.
In the corresponding application in /store the Validity Period is set to 120 (for testing purposes).
In /carbon, at the service provider in the "OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration", the "User Access Token Expiry Time", the "Application Access Token Expiry Time" and the "Id Token Expiry Time" are all set to 120.
But the generated token has always an expiry time of 3600 seconds.